# Do a string operations on a hex file with java

Tags: java, io, hex

I have a hex file that contains a lot of bytes, I need to split these bytes according to a specific byte, for example

```
f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 b7 7a 7a e5 db 40 2 0 c0 0 0 9 18 16 0 e3 1 40 0 0 3f 20 f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 41 bc 7a e5 db 40 2 0 c0 1 0 9 18 16 0 e3 1 40 0 0 3f 20 f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 53 3f 7b e5 db 40 2 0 c0 3 0 9 2 19 24 3d 0 22 68 1 db 9
```

When ever I see "f0" I want to split the bytes and store them, to be like these

```
f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 b7 7a 7a e5 db 40 2 0 c0 0 0 9 18 16 0 e3 1 40 0 0 3f 20
f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 41 bc 7a e5 db 40 2 0 c0 1 0 9 18 16 0 e3 1 40 0 0 3f 20
f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 53 3f 7b e5 db 40 2 0 c0 3 0 9 2 19 24 3d 0 22 68 1 db 9
```

and for each one of these I wand to treat it as an array of characters to do some string operations.

How could I store these patterns and how could I treat it as a characters to do the operations.

Here you are what I have tried to do

```
    String filename = "C:\\tm09888.123";
    FileInputStream in = null;
    int readHexFile = 0; 
    char hexToChar = ' ';
    String[] bytes = new String[10];

    try
    {            
        in = new FileInputStream(filename); 

        while((readHexFile = in.read()) != -1)
        {       
            if (Integer.toHexString(readHexFile).equals("f0"))
            {
                System.out.print("\n\n\n");
            }
            System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(readHexFile) + " ");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(NARSSTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  

}
```

I successfully split the patterns but how could I store it and do a string operations on each one of them

Comment: add what you read to a `StringBuffer` and save the Strings you want into a `List`

Comment: @jlordo Why a comment and not an answer? Sounds like a plausible approach.

Comment: the comment was quicker to type than my answer ;) see below.

Comment: You don't have a hex file. You have a binary file. Everybody does. All files are binary.

Answer (score 2):

If the file is binary which you want to print as a series of hexidecimal numbers you can do

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream());
try {
    boolean first = true;
    for(int b; (b = in.read()) >= 0;) {
        if (b == 0xF0 && !first)
            System.out.println();
        first = false;
        System.out.printf("%x ", b);
    }
} finally {
    in.close();
    System.out.println();
}
```

If the file is hexidecimal as text you can do

```
String text = FileUtils.readFileAsString(file, "iso-8859-1");
text = text.replaceAll(" f0", "\nf0");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file2, text);
```

or to break this into lines you can do

```
String text = FileUtils.readFileAsString(file, "iso-8859-1");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(text.replaceAll(" f0", "\nf0")));
for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null;) {
   // process one line
}
```

using [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) or you own method to do similarly.

Comment: The OP has a binary file, not a text file; `readFileAsString` is not a good approach.

Comment: `readFileAsString()` works perfectly for binary files as long as you specify an encoding (which you should always do; `readFileToString(File file)` is a bug). `"iso-8859-1"` is a 1:1 mapping that turns every byte in the input into a single character in the string. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lawrey, but how could I do the string operation on each one of them.

Comment: Both examples do the operation on all the data. Do you want to do another operation, if so what is it?

Comment: I want to treat each pattern as a separate string, to use all string method. For example 
'f0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 b7 7a 7a e5 db 40 2 0 c0 0 0 9 18 16 0 e3 1 40 0 0 3f 20'
I want to take 'f0' and save it in a separate variable and take '01' and save it in a separate variable an so on for all the pattern.

Comment: I have added example of how to process this as "lines"

Comment: Good, but can we do it using only java classes and where all patterns stored ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
while((readHexFile = in.read()) != -1) {
    String str = Integer.toHexString(readHexFile);
    if (str.equals("f0")) {
         String string = strb.toString();
         if (!string.isEmpty()) {
              list.add(new String("f0" + string)); // here
         }
         strb = new StringBuilder();
    } else {
         strb.append(str);
    }
}
String string = strb.toString();
if (!string.isEmpty()) {
    list.add(new String("f0" + string)); // here
}
// now you have all the strings in the list.
```

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer if you can use StringBuilder.

Comment: Thanks jlordo, but when I use `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` this error appear ( diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6 ), I use jdk 7

Comment: Diamond Operator is only Java 7 and up. A tiny little research would have guided you to this solution: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: Thanks @jlordo, I want now to save each item in the list to a new text file all with the same name, for example pattern1 pattern2 and so on. and also save all the patterns in one text file. How I could this in each item in the list.

Comment: Thank you would be upvote and accept ;) I don't clearly understand what you are trying to do, but there are many questions and tutorials on how to write things into files.

Comment: I tried to print each item in the list 
`for (String s : list)            
System.out.println(s + "\n\n");`
and it did not give the expected result :)
`15000000b77a7ae5db4020c000918160e3140003f20
1500000041bc7ae5db4020c010918160e3140003f20
15000000cafd7ae5db4020c020979f728042e44e23f0`

Comment: since this seems to be a whole new question, I advise you to ask a new question containing your current code, input examples, your output and your expected output. Also don't forget to accept an answer here, the one that helped to solve the question of your post.

Comment: It is the same question :) .. I tried your code and it should save all patterns begin with "F0" in the list but the list items are not begin with "F0"

Comment: check out my edit, i changed the two lines which have the `// here` comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just convert the hex file into string and do the string operation?

Use FileReader and read the file into memory as one big string (if the file is reasonable in size). In the underlying InputStringReader, you must specify US-ASCII, to not use default UTF-16. Then do string.split() by the character corresponding to the f0 value in ASCII, which is Icelandic ð:

```
char f0 = 'ð';

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "US-ASCII")));

//read reader into string, trivial...

String[] split = readString.split(f0);
for(String s : split){
    s = 'ð' + s;
    //do your work on the string here
}
```